# this._destroy is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I have a backbone.js + jquery ui + jquery mobile app and for some reason .remove() throws: this._destroy is not a function error in the jquery library.  Anyone else run into this?  I'm guessing its an issue with 'this' referring to a different element but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The difference could be that you're calling .remove() on a backbone object versus a jQuery object -- both Backbone.View objects and jQuery objects feature .remove() methods -- perhaps you're calling it on one type, thinking it's the other?

Comment: Yeah, if I do $(e.currentTarget).remove() it's fine, or even $(e.currentTarget).parent().remove() but $(e.currentTarget).closes('tr').remove() throws the error

Comment: That sounds like it could potentially be a bug; you might want to consider trying to work up a bug report for that.

Answer (score 0):

Found a native JS workaround:

```
var thisCancel = $(e.currentTarget).closest('tr').prop('id');
var dRemove = document.getElementById(thisCancel);
dRemove.parentNode.removeChild(dRemove);
```